# Makefile rule causing unnecessary rebuild

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got a rule that checks if a certain environment variable has been set:

```
check-env:
  ifndef NODE_ENV
    $(error NODE_ENV is undefined)
  endif
```

I then have stuff that depend on it (which should fail if `NODE_ENV` isn't set):

```
sql/schema.js: sql/schema.sql check-env
  ...
```

My issue is that `check-env` always causes a rebuild, what should I actually be doing to achieve what I want in a reasonably modular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing this in the recipe of a target?  Why not just put it out in the main part of your makefile?

```
ifndef NODE_ENV
  $(error NODE_ENV is undefined)
endif
```

If you really want to have this done through rules, your best bet (assuming you're using a "new-enough" version of GNU make) is to use order-only prerequisites like this:

```
check-env:
        $(if $(NODE_ENV),,$(error NODE_ENV is undefined))

sql/schema.js: sql/schema.sql | check-env
        ...
```

(note the pipe symbol `|`).  See the manual for details.

Comment: Just because not ever rule in the Makefile needs that variable set.